# Product images not showing after server migration prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5, server-migration

I have migrated my prestashop 1.5.6 e-commerce site to a new server,

Process i did was just upload the files to new server and import the db.

I cleaned the Cache/smarty/compile and Cache/smarty/cache folders and left the index.php file.

I tried regenerating thumbnails from Preferences/images page but didn't work and gave "Internal server error".

I changed the process configuration to FcgidBusyTimeout 3600 in /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf

I tried again to regenerate and this time, it is gave that : Original images not found in /img/p/1/2/xxx, But in reality all my images are in /img/p/xxxx.png

I tried using the Move Images to New image structure function in Preferences/images page and it created the structure but 1400+ images are not found now !!

Anyhelp will be more then welcome !

Updated : 27 June 2014
I lost hope after 48 hrs of finding and trying different solutions, reverted version back to backup copy of store, and not managing the store anymore. lost client..

Comment: Still no solution for this issue? please to share with us if any. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Did you regenerated your `.htaccess`? To do so, go to preferences>SEO and URLs and click save. This will automatically refresh a line in that file depending on your new server configuration.

If not, try to regenerate the thumbnails (Preferences>images>regenerate thumbs). Since you have a lot of images, Try to regenerate type by type because the process take a lot of time and it is better to know where it stops if it is interrupted.

Of course, all manips are better done in development environment.

good luck.

Comment: Saved me. Very Thanks! Changing `ph_shop_url.domain` in database is not a good solution. Your way is best. don't forget to clear cache also.

Answer (score 3):

For others who may not yet get the answer

Go to Preference -> SEO and URLS.

There you will get a block for shop detail named as "Set Shop URL", There you have to change the details for Shop domain, SSL domain, Base URI as per your server details.

Answer (score 1):

Update domain in:

- your **[www root]/.htaccess**
- **ps_shop_url** db table

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the suffix of the images? Sometimes it change from _home to _homedefault.

Answer (score 1):

You could check these:

- default image paths `_PS_PROD_IMG_DIR_` and `_PS_IMG_DIR_`
  are changed in `defines.inc.php` and rest of path is as expected
- value for `PS_IMAGE_QUALITY` was changed manually to `jpg` instead of `png` in `ps_configuration` table